# Prediction using Hidden Markov Models

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models, hidden-markov-model, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to model financial time series data using Hidden Markov Models. This question is related to time series analysis in general. Can I create the model on previous few days data and use that model for regime estimation of current day's data (The way we use other unsupervised learning models )?  Or is it like the model needs to be constantly updated with today's time series observations for estimation of the next observation ?